# How to save results for each while loop in python?

Tags: python, excel, while-loop, saving-data

as you can see from my code there will be 150 dx value like dx(1) for j=50, dx(2) for j=51---dx(150) for j=149. I want to write all dx (upto 149) value in one column of "foobar.xls" file. Presently, I found in xls file, only the value of dx(150). so that is my problem. Sorry for improper questioning. (I`m new here).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np 
import xlrd
import xlwt


wb = xlrd.open_workbook('Scatter plot.xlsx')
sh1 = wb.sheet_by_name('T180')
sh2=wb.sheet_by_name("T181")
sh3=wb.sheet_by_name("Sheet1")


x= np.array([sh1.col_values(1,start_rowx=50, end_rowx=299)])
x1= np.array([sh2.col_values(1, start_rowx=48, end_rowx=200)])

print x1

j=50

while j<200:
    y=np.array([sh1.cell_value(j,1)])
    condition = [(x1<=(sh1.cell_value(j,1)+100)) & (x1>=(sh1.cell_value(j,1)-200)) ]
    dx=y-x1[condition]
    j+=1
    print dx

workbook = xlwt.Workbook() 
sheet = workbook.add_sheet("Sheet1")

i=1
for n in dx:
    sheet.write(i, 0,n)
    i=i+1

workbook.save("foobar.xls")
```

Comment: your question is not readable

Comment: No explanation, bad editing --> Flag

Comment: i want to edit the question. How to edit the question? Anyone please help.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please go through the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) and the [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) sections to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.

Comment: Where do you want to save your results?

Comment: "foobar.xls" file

Comment: Make a serious effort to explain exactly what your question is. It is not at all clear what you want help with.

Comment: @jwpfox                                                                                             Dear, as you can see from my code there will be 150 dx value like dx(1) for j=50, dx(2) for j=51---dx(150) for j=149. I want to write all dx (upto 149) value in one column of "foobar.xls" file. Presently, I found in xls file, only the value of dx(150). so that is my problem. Sorry for improper questioning. (I`m new here).

Comment: So why aren't you writing the dx value to the file in the loop? Directly under (or immediately before) where you print the value?

Comment: Sorry, brother I don`t have enough knowledge to write the code as you suggested. Would you please help me to learn how to write that part. Thanks @jwpfox

Comment: Did you write the original code?

Comment: yes but taking help from the website example. I started python for last 3 months only.. so its tough for me to write accurately.

Comment: Its working like this way. Thanks for our nice comments and helpful mind.                                                                                                          j=50
i=1
while j<300:
    x=np.array([sh1.cell_value(j,1)])
    condition = [(x1<=(sh1.cell_value(j,1)+100)) & (x1>=(sh1.cell_value(j,1)-200)) ]
    dx=x-x1[condition]
    j+=1
       for n in dx:
        sheet.write(i, 0,n)
        i+=1
       
    print dx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Its working like this way. Thanks for our nice comments and helpful mind.

j=50
i=1
while j<300:
    x=np.array([sh1.cell_value(j,1)])
    condition = [(x1<=(sh1.cell_value(j,1)+100)) & (x1>=     (sh1.cell_value(j,1)-200)) ]
    dx=x-x1[condition]
    j+=1
       for n in dx:
        sheet.write(i, 0,n)
        i+=1
     print dx
```